# Finding duplicate entries

Tags: pandas

I am working with the 515k Hotel Reviews dataset from Kaggle. There are 1492 unique hotel names and 1493 unique addresses. So at first it would appear that one (or possibly more) hotel has more than one address. But, if I do a groupby.count on the data, I get 1494 whether I groupby HotelName followed by Address or if I reverse the order.

In order to make this reproducible, hopefully this simplification will suffice:

```
data = {
        'HotelName': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
        'Address': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['HotelName', 'Address'])

df['HotelName'].unique().shape[0]  # Returns 4
df['Address'].unique().shape[0]  # Returns 5
df.groupby(['Address', 'HotelName']).count().shape[0]  # Returns 6
df.groupby(['Address', 'HotelName']).count().shape[0]  # Returns 6
```

I would like to find the hotel names that have different addresses. So in my example, I would like to find the A and C along with their addresses (1,2 and 3,5 respectively). That code should be enough for me to also find the addresses that have duplicate hotel names.

Comment: "everyone who ignores SQL is doomed to reimplement it, poorly"

Comment: @wildplasser, I'm trying to get into data science and am learning python and sql. I had planned to mess with this dataset with pandas, then go back through it with sql just to practice them both. However, you got me wondering. Do you guys ever use more than one language while working on a dataset?  For example, would you clean it in sql, then import to pandas to do seaborn visualizations on it? If so, how often do you use multiple languages on the same data?

Comment: code != data. Just wait till your dataset is too large to fit in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, we can check which hotel has more then 1 *unique adress* with `groupby.transform(nunqiue)`:

```
m = df.groupby('HotelName')['Address'].transform('nunique').ne(1)
print(df.loc[m])

   HotelName  Address
0          A        1
2          C        3
4          A        1
6          C        3
8          A        2
11         C        3
12         C        5
```

If you want to get a more concise view on which the duplicates are, use `groupby.agg(set)`:

```
df.loc[m].groupby('HotelName')['Address'].agg(set).reset_index(name='addresses')

  HotelName addresses
0         A    {1, 2}
1         C    {3, 5}
```

---

**Step by step:**

`transform(nunique)` gives us the amount of unique adresses next to each row

```
df.groupby('HotelName')['Address'].transform('nunique')

0     2
1     1
2     2
3     1
4     2
5     1
6     2
7     1
8     2
9     1
10    1
11    2
12    2
Name: Address, dtype: int64
```

Then we check which rows are not equal (`ne`) to `1` and filter those:

```
df.groupby('HotelName')['Address'].transform('nunique').ne(1)

0      True
1     False
2      True
3     False
4      True
5     False
6      True
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
Name: Address, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nunique` groupby aggregator:

```
>>> n_uniq = df.groupby('HotelName')['Address'].nunique()
>>> n_uniq
    HotelName
A    2
B    1
C    2
D    1
Name: Address, dtype: int64
```

If you want to look at the distinct hotels with more than one address in the original dataframe,

```
>>> hotels_with_mult_addr = n_uniq.index[n_uniq > 1]
>>> df[df['HotelName'].isin(hotels_with_mult_addr)].drop_duplicates()
   HotelName  Address
0          A        1
2          C        3
8          A        2
12         C        5
```

Answer (score 0):

`Groupby` didn't do what you were expected. After you did the `groupby` here is what you got

```
  HotelName  Address
0         A        1
4         A        1 


  HotelName  Address
8         A        2 


   HotelName  Address
1          B        2
5          B        2
9          B        2
10         B        2 


   HotelName  Address
2          C        3
6          C        3
11         C        3 


  HotelName  Address
3         D        4
7         D        4 


   HotelName  Address
12         C        5
```

There are indeed 6 combinations!

If you want to know the duplication in each group, you should check the row index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the long way to do it, where in newdf['count'] == 1 is unique

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['HotelName', 'Address'])
df = df.sort_values(by = ['HotelName','Address']).reset_index(drop = True)

count = df.groupby(['HotelName','Address'])['Address'].count().reset_index(drop = True)

df['rownum'] = df.groupby(['HotelName','Address']).cumcount()+1
dfnew = df[df['rownum']==1].reset_index(drop = True).drop(columns = 'rownum')
dfnew['count'] = count

dfnew
```